# How can I retrieve data from a external URL to show in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

As a learning exercise I'm trying to retrieve the *track_artist_name* from a url used by a radio sation to show the song being played.
This could be a case of "Same-Origin-Policy" but I dont have enough knowledge to tell.
Could someone please help me to workaround the conflict ? Also, I know "this.responseText" will show everything, I will try to filter it once I can retrieve the Data, but if you feel generous and want to trow me also that bone, I will be really grateful to you. Thank you : )

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="data">
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get Data</button>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
        this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://np.tritondigital.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=XERC_FM&numberToFetch=1", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be sending the request to your server and getting its contents backend where you won't be affected by the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: As Spectric said, you generally run into too many roadblocks trying to accomplish this type of thing on the client-side exclusively (unless the 3rd party explicitly cooperates in their server's http headers). Do this instead using your server-side framework, then pass it along to the client from there.

Comment: "This could be a case of "Same-Origin-Policy" but I dont have enough knowledge to tell." — Open the browser's developer tools. Look at the console. Read the error messages. (As a rule of thumb, if you don't know how to debug the language you are are using then you should be learning how to do that from an introductory tutorial before resorting to asking for help with a specific problem)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. Cold you please point me on the right direction to  accomplish "using your server-side framework, then pass it along to the client" ?